# How to install psycopg2 for python 3.5.1? Where can I find the suitable wheel file? I am using Windows 7 32 bit

Tags: python, pip, psycopg2, easy-install

I Tried installing psycopg2 using the following command in cmd prompt:

C:\Python\Python35-32\Scripts>pip install psycopg2-2.7.3-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.wh
l
**psycopg2-2.7.3-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.**
The above line is the error I am getting. I downloaded the wheel file from the following link:
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#psycopg

But I am unable to find the suitable version of wheel for my system and python version. I will not be able to install directly from online using pip. I have to find a way to install from the file which is present locally. Please help me doing this. I am using Windows 7 32 bit and my python version is 3.5.1.

Comment: Use `psycopg2-2.7.3-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl`

Comment: getting the same error for that too

Comment: Try to update pip: `C:\Python\Python35-32\python.exe -m pip install -U pip`

Comment: "Requirement already up-to-date: pip in c:\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages" is what i am getting